# how to add textbox in table using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just want to add a textbox in table at runtime using javascript. Anybody know...?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Wow holy moly what's with all the JQuery answers.

There are two ways of doing this:

**Appending item to the DOM**

This is probably the best way:

```
var input = document.createElement("input"); 
input.type = "text"; 
container.appendChild(input);
```

**InnerHTML**

This is not such a good method, innerHTML is dubious from a standards perspective.  I would highly recommend using the DOM method above, but here is an alternative:

```
document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML += "<input type='text' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this source code will guide you through the point which you are looking for !

tableWidget = new YK.TableFactory(3,5,false, false);

textbox = new YK.Entry();

```
tableWidget.attach(
  textbox, 
  0, 1, 0, 1, 
  {align: YK.JUSTIFY_LEFT, fill: true}, 
  {align: YK.JUSTIFY_TOP, fill: true}, 
  1, 1
```

);

Answer (score -2):

This will insert a textarea to the first td of the first tr of the first table on a page (using jQuery). But i guess it will send you on the right way

```
$('table:first tr:first td:first').append('<textarea>my text</textarea>');
```

Comment: Seriously? Loading a whole framework to append an element to the DOM?

Answer (score -2):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you can do like this:

```
$('<input type="text" name="" id="" />').appendTo('#id_of_my_td');
```